# Why isn't this code executing correctly (video)?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity (3.4) Monodevelop (2.4.2) and it's not executing the code properly when I step through it in the debugger.  Here's a link to the video that shows it, please run it at 720p and fullscreen it...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGN7kxMUqjA

Also, here are some screenshots showing the debugger displaying really strange values when I mouseover a variable.  Here's what it looks like when it correctly shows the value of the xSectionPixel in the first if block...
[image]  And here's what it looks like when it incorrectly shows the value of the xSectionPixel in the second if block...
[image]
This is also the line of code where it starts executing code incorrectly.

What would cause this?

I've tried reinstalling the tools, using a fresh copy of the code from the repository, I even set it all up on a different computer with a different OS (Win 7) and it always does the same thing. Doesn't that mean it has to be my code then?

It's also worth noting that I'm using SVN to push/pull the code from a repository and my local copy exists in my Dropbox folder.

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!  Here's the code as well if you can spot anything that might be breaking things (i.e. the way I'm using floats and ints maybe?)

```
Vector2 textureCoordToHexGridCoord(int textX, int textY)
    {
        Vector2 hexGridCoord = new Vector2();
        float m = hexH / hexR;

        int xsection = (int)(textX / (hexH + hexS));
        int ysection = (int)(textY / (2 * hexR));

        int xSectionPixel = (int)(textX - xsection * (hexH + hexS));
        int ySectionPixel = (int)(textY - ysection * (2 * hexR));

        //A Section
        if(xsection % 2 == 0)
        {
            hexGridCoord.x = xsection;
            hexGridCoord.y = ysection;

            if(xSectionPixel < (hexH - ySectionPixel * m))
            {
                hexGridCoord.x--;
                hexGridCoord.y--;
            }

            if(xSectionPixel < (-hexH + ySectionPixel * m))
            {
                hexGridCoord.x--;
            }
        }

        //B Section
        else
        {
            if(xSectionPixel >= hexR)
            {
                if(ySectionPixel < (2 * hexH - xSectionPixel * m))
                {
                    hexGridCoord.x = xsection - 1;
                    hexGridCoord.y = ysection - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    hexGridCoord.x = xsection;
                    //hexGridCoord.y = ysection;
                    hexGridCoord.y = ysection - 1;
                }
            }

            if(xSectionPixel < hexR)
            {
                if(ySectionPixel < (xSectionPixel * m))
                {
                    hexGridCoord.x = xsection;
                    //hexGridCoord.y = ysection - 1;
                    hexGridCoord.y = ysection;
                }
                else
                {
                    hexGridCoord.x = xsection - 1;
                    hexGridCoord.y = ysection;
                }
            }
        }

        return hexGridCoord;
    }
```

Comment: If it's a Mono compiler hickup, did you try to extract the code into another method or as a static method within another class and call this (with an ugly bunch of params)? Did you try renaming the class? Do you have a previous revision in svn that is working?

Comment: Ok, I try all those suggestions and it's still acting broken.  Also, I added some screenshots to my question above showing the broken mouseover values where the code starts executing incorrectly.  Your thoughts?

Comment: The wrong stepping behaviour from the video reminds me of situations where the code is out of sync. OK, still possible that it's a bug in Mono, but most of the bugs are made by us ;) Did you stop dropbox daemon, add a logging statement and rebuild?

Answer (score 7):

I have no specific experience with the frameworks you use, but I do have a lot of experience with debuggers.
The debugger behavior you see can happen in one of two scenarios (that I can think of...)

1. The symbol files and executing code are not synchronized with your source code, usually the IDE should detect that, but it some cases it doesn't, the solution is to delete all binaries, recompile and try again.
2. A bug in the debugger or the debugger extension (used to debug in the specific environment your are in, i.e. unity/monodevelop).

If you are unable to resolve it, I would add logging to your code and use it to really understand what happens.

Comment: I have seen this in the past as well when the debug symbols are out of sync for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, Asher, Kyle.  I've tried reinstalling the tools, using a fresh copy of the code from the repository, I even set it all up on a different computer with a different OS (Win 7) and it always does the same thing.  Doesn't that mean it has to be my code then?

Comment: no. it means a bug in the debugger.... your last resort at this point is to use logging to figure out the flow of the code.

Comment: about the debugger bug, try isolating it and sumbit a bug to the MonoDevelop team: http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Reporting_Bugs

Comment: I will submit a bug report, but for the time being, that doesn't help me keep my job.

Comment: That's what you get for using Unity and Mono! If you wrote native code this would not be happening.

Comment: @Sneakyness No, in that case you'd never be able to diagnose the debugger issue. :p  If software is to blame, it's likely Unity3D.

Answer (score 2):

I saw similar behavior on MonoDevelop with WinForms applications, solved with reinstalling debugger.

Have you tried that or using Visual Studio to verify that the problem is in the code?

Comment: no i haven't, but i'll try that, thank you.  it seems highly unlikely that will fix the problem tho, considering the problem persists when I run the code on different computers.

Comment: The problem most likely in the MonoDevelop's debugger

Answer (score 2):

Do you have optimizations turned on? If so, does disabling them make stepping any less erratic?

Enabling optimizations is one thing I can think of that no one else has mentioned yet that could potentially cause what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, jstedfast! I'll look into it and let you know what I find.

Comment: I can't seem to find any way to turn off optimizations in Unity Monodevelop

Comment: Under the Project Options dialog, in the tree view on the left, navigate to Build / Compiler. There should be a checkbox on the right called "Enable optimizations", make sure it's off.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try removing you breakpoints, setting a new one, and stepping through the code?

The reason I ask is there are ways that you can set values using breakpoints. A very similar thing happened to me and was convinced that there was a compiler bug. After stepping through the CLR and number of other things with no answer, we stumbled across a breakpoint that was set earlier for testing, and never removed.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of behavior usually happens to me when I'm debugging a multithreaded part of an application.

What happens is that while you debug several threads at once, the debugger in visual studio keeps switching between them without notifying you by default.
Now since threads are not executing the same lines at the same time, you got unexpected "jumps".

I believe it is widely used in game developpement, so in your case you got two choices:

1) Make only one thread run while you make your debugging.

2) Make unit tests <= That's the "best practice".
 
   You can start by having a look at [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)

Comment: I don't mind the downvotes, but please explain why. Hit and run is lame.

Comment: You were likely downvoted because this doesn't answer the question ("What would cause this?")

Answer (score 0):

The first issue most likely has something to do with the sequence points in the JITed code. These are the points where the debugger can stop. They're computed by the runtime based on the IL and debug symbols generated by the compiler, therefore this is most likely a runtime or compiler bug. I don't know what version of the Mono runtime and compiler is being used by Unity, but it's quite that this has been fixed in a newer version. If you can reproduce this using a "normal" console app using the latest official MonoDevelop and Mono 2.10.x, please file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a test case. If not, please ask Unity to upgrade their version of Mono.

The second issue looks like an issue in MonoDevelop's expression resolver that's used to resolve the symbol under the mouse. This may have been fixed in a newer version of MonoDevelop - likewise, please try to repro with the official MonoDevelop 2.8.4, and file a bug if it's still an issue.